# Autohotkey F4 script does not work on Excel 2013

Tags: excel, autohotkey, excel-2013

I'm trying to build a very simple script for Autohotkey that binds the *F4* key to a specific combinantion of keys (*Win+4*). It works perfectly on all applications but one: Excel 2013. It even works on Excel 2010, but not on Excel 2013.

Mapping *F2* to *Win+2* works just fine, including in Excel 2013.

Is there a workaround for this? I've already tried to map *F4* to a bunch of different key combinations, but none of those worked on Excel 2013.

Here is my simple autohotkey script, by the way

```
#2:: F2
#4:: F4
```

Comment: I do not have Excel 2013 to test with, but is it possible that F4 is a hotkey registered in the application? If I recall, those can conflict with AHK hotkeys.

Comment: What do your *'autohotkey script'** have to do with Excel programming?

Comment: @ozdrgnaDiies Thanks for your comment. I've checked the official documentation and realized that the registered hotkeys are the same. I'll try some workarounds here to solve the conflicts. Thanks

Comment: @Jeeped You tell me? Perhaps there would be a workaround on VBA that could disable registered Excel hotkeys, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way here, thanks for the comments.

By using the $ operator, we can then use the Send method, which forces the active application to override its default keys and receive the corresponding keystroke.

Here's the workaround

```
$#4::
#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN
 Send {F4}
 return
#IfWinActive
```